# How to utilize dictionary data set for text classification?

Tags: classification, nlp, word2vec, word-embeddings, text

I have a dataset similar to newsgroup20 for classification. With the training dataset, I have a dictionary data set that explains some jargons in the training dataset. These both are different data set, So how will i utilize the dictionary dataset for improving my model accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach [LEARNING TO COMPUTE WORD EMBEDDINGS ON THE FLY](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.00286.pdf). Using additional auxiliary data you can substitute jargons using definitions from dictionary. In this case, jargons  embeddings will become more relevant, in semantic sense .